# how to re-define the `__add__` method for `int`?

Tags: python, operators

I want to re-define the `__add__` method for `int` so that the usage would be like this:

```
 >> 1+2
 => "1 plus 2"

 >> (1).__add__(2)
 => "1 plus 2"
```

I tried this:

```
 >>> int.__add__ = lambda self, x: str(self)+" plus " + str(x)
```

However, it throws an exception:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: can't set attributes of built-in/extension type 'int'
```

Does anyone have ideas about why I can't redefine the `__add__` method like this? And is there other way to do this?

Comment: You'll have to subclass `int()`. Built-in types are not arbitrarily extensible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

create your own class which overrides the `__add__` method of `int` class.

```
In [126]: class myint(int):
    def __add__(self,a):
        print "{0} plus {1}".format(self,a)
   .....:         

In [127]: a=myint(5)

In [128]: b=myint(6)

In [129]: a+b
5 plus 6
```

Answer (score 0):

Although not best practice, you could use [forbiddenfruit](https://github.com/clarete/forbiddenfruit) to overwrite the `__add__` method. Usage:

```
>>> from forbiddenfruit import curse
>>> curse(int, '__add__', lambda x, y: f"{x} plus {y}")
>>> 1 + 2
'1 plus 2'
```